# Performing mysql update based on passed variable from link?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've built a list of links based off of an array from a select query.

Linking to the page in question works fine, but I've added a link option to each to delete the page in question. The only issue is, I'm wondering the best way to pass the page ID of the given page into the query that deletes (deactivates) the page.

I build my page links like this:

```
  <?php foreach($result as $page): ?>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 d-flex" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
      <div class="card text-center flex-fill">
          <h2><?php echo $page["title"] ?></h2> 
          <p><?php echo $page["Name"]?></p>
          <a target="_blank" href="showpage.php?pageid=<?php echo $page['id'] ?>">View Page</a>
          <a href="">Edit Page</a>
          <a href="">Delete Page</a> <!--this is where I need to pass $page['id'] and use it in the query below-->
      </div>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach?>
```

The query to delete/deactivate:

```
$deletePage = "
UPDATE pages
set active = 0
where id = /*this is page ID from previous link*/
";

$performDelete = $mysqlConn->query($deletePage);
```

What is the best practice for me to pass the pageID of the link into this query?

Comment: *"What is the best practice for me to pass the pageID of the link into this query?"*  - **A:** use a prepared statement if that's what you're asking. Question is a bit unclear for me though as to what you want to do here. Do you want to keep something but use it later if needed? If so, then set a boolean flag in another column related to it, might even have to use a relational table. If I didn't answer what you're asking, you might need to elaborate.

Comment: Definitely, so I don't want to delete the record which is why I'm just setting the active column to 0. All I'm trying to do is let the user confirm deletion, perform the deletion/deactivation, and then refresh the page with a little toast/alert that it was deleted

Comment: You can use a conditional statement `if/else` in order to get their confirmation. An added "enter **YES** here" where you could check if the GET array is set and equal to "YES" would also be of added benefit.

Comment: That makes sense as well, and I may actually go that route. Currently I'm just trying to test that it actually deletes based on the correct page ID. Could I make my href refresh the page and still pass the value?

Comment: Hm... you may need to use sessions if a refresh happens and that you want the user to keep the information that was saved but not confirmed.

Comment: Maybe I'll do what you said earlier, but I'll call my functions file as the url and put a header in there to refresh after delete

Comment: Sure Tom, whatever you think will work best :-) Btw, not to overstep the answer below. You can use `$id=(int)$_GET['var'];` to help against injection, given it will always be an integer, if you don't want to add all of that extra prepared statement code. They are great to work with, just a bit of overkill sometimes, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the target page through as a URL parameter on the first page, so it will be available on the second page via `$_GET`, so the standard structure would be:

`$deletePage = "UPDATE pages set active=0 where id=$_GET['pageid']";`

**However**, note that the above is open to attacks; it's trivial for a user to simply modify the value in their address bar, and thus update the wrong row. In fact, with a bit of SQL injection, it's even possible for a user to completely delete your entire database with the above PHP / SQL.

The best way to avoid this is paramaterised queries (I assume MySQLi in the following):

```
$stmt = $mysqlConn->prepare("UPDATE pages set active=0 where id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['pageid']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Note that you'll still want to assure that the user viewing the page is authorised to make the `UPDATE` command, most likely by checking against their `$_SESSION`.

Comment: They're using `?pageid` and not `page_id`.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense but will this work if I just want to refresh the page? I'm going to ask the user if they're sure they want to delete and if so, perform the deletion and refresh to the current page with an alert that it was deleted

Comment: Also, the link is being used to go to view the page. For this link to delete, I just want to refresh the current page

Comment: Fixed `pageid`. Yes, this would in theory work for standard refreshes, so long as the `pageid` is in the URL parameters. And you would need to use JavaScript to handle popup confirmations (keep in mind PHP is only server-side). From there it would probably be best to do an AJAX POST request to your PHP page that contains the core logic, assuming the user hits 'yes' or similiar on the JavaScript side.

Answer (score -1):

Pass it in link and get it in second page using $_GET['id']

```
<a href="deletepage.php/id?$page['id']">Delete Page</a>
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer at all, but regardless, I'm not passing it in a link. The link above is going to 'View Page'. If the Delete Page link is clicked, I want to pass the id, perform the delete and refresh the page

Comment: Oke but not create view just make controller name deletepage.php and write last line in that page 
   header ("location: firtspage.php");